# Show that $R \circ S$ is a rotation about an axis and determine the angle of rotation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Let $r$ and $s$ be two incident and perpendicular lines. Let $R:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ be a rotation of $\pi/2$ about $r$ and $S:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ a rotation of $\pi/2$ about $s$.

The exercise asks me to show that $R \circ S$ is a rotation about an axis and determine the angle of rotation, but honestly I don't know where to start since I'm just getting started with these kind of exercises.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. We won't just do it for you.

Comment: @EthanBolker I completely understand but the thing is that my professor puts exercises in exams regarding topics that he never taught during lessons so it's pretty hard to do some exercises without even knowing where to possibly start. I know it's rude to ask for having the exercise completely solved so I'm only going to be asking for some hints at least...

Comment: A good place to start with these problems is to try and visualize what's happening using specific examples. If you take $r$ as the $z-$axis and $s$ as the $x-$ axis, how does $R\circ S$ act on the point $(0,0,1)$? Try to use this specific example to develop a conjecture and then prove that your conjecture is valid.

Comment: @MatthewH. So basically I have to apply the rotation S first (right?) and the point moves on the y axis and then applying R it moves on the x axis. This means that the rotation is about the y axis in the end? If I show this graphically can I say it's proved or do I need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach which doesn't require matrices. I'll use the following property of 3-D rotations:

> A rotation of angle $\theta$ about a line $a$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ is
> the composition of the reflections $\Pi_\alpha$ and $\Pi_\beta$ about
> any two planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ having $a$ in common and forming a
> diedral angle of $\theta/2$.

Let's take then $r$ as the $x$ axis and $s$ as the $y$ axis. To represent rotation $R$ as the composition of two reflections, we must choose two planes meeting at $r$ and forming an angle of $45°$ between them. The same for rotation $S$. The trick consists in choosing a plane which is the same for both rotations, that is the plane $z=0$ containing $r$ and $s$. We can then choose a plane through $r$ at $45°$ with $z=0$, for instance plane $y=z$, and a plane through $s$ at $45°$ with $z=0$, for instance plane $x=z$. We have then:
$$
R=\Pi_{y=z}\circ\Pi_{z=0}
\quad\text{and}\quad
S=\Pi_{z=0}\circ\Pi_{x=z}
$$
and from that we obtain:
$$
R\circ S=\Pi_{y=z}\circ\Pi_{z=0}\circ\Pi_{z=0}\circ\Pi_{x=z}
=\Pi_{y=z}\circ\Pi_{x=z},
$$
where we used the fact that the composition of a reflection with itself is the identity.

But this is then a rotation, about the line common to planes $x=z$ and $y=z$ (namely $x=y=z$), of an angle $\theta$ which is twice the angle between the planes. To find $\theta$ we can compute the scalar product of the normal vectors to the planes:
$$
\cos{\theta\over2}={(1,0,-1)\cdot(0,1,-1)\over\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2}
={1\over2},
$$
whence $\theta=120°$.

Answer (score 1):

Since rotation of the world frame does not change the final angle of rotation, we can take line $s$ to the $x$ axis, and $r$ to be the $y$ axis.  Now rotation about the $x$ axis by an angle $\dfrac{\pi}{2} $ is given by

$R_s = R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1\\ 0 && 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

And the rotation matrix about the $r$ line by $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is given by

$R_r = R_y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

The overall rotation is

$A = R \circ S = R_r R_s = R_y R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \\-1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now we need to identify the rotation matrix $A$.  From Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula

$A = {a a}^T + (I - {a a}^T) \cos(\theta) + S_a \sin(\theta) $

where $S_a$ is the skew-symmetric matrix corresponding to cross multiplication the axis $a$ with a vector.

The trace of $A$ is

$\text{Trace}(A) = 1 + 2 \cos(\theta) $

Looking at $A$, its trace is $0$ , therefore, $ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \dfrac{2 \pi}{3} = 120^\circ $

The axis can be found from the off-diagonal entries,

$ \dfrac{ A_{12} - A_{21} }{ 2 \sin(\theta) } = - a_z $

$ \dfrac{ A_{13} - A_{31} }{ 2 \sin(\theta) } =  a_y $

$ \dfrac{ A_{23} - A_{32} }{ 2 \sin(\theta) } = - a_x $

Hence, the axis is given by

$ a = (a_x, a_y, a_z) = (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ) $